# My query is not working

Tags: laravel

```
DB::table('foduu_products as fp' )->select("fp.id", "fp.name", "fp.slug"," fp.status", "fc.name", "fc.slug as category_slug", "fp.approved", "ff.filepath", "fdp.product_id","fdp.type", "fdp.sku", "fdp.regular_price", "fdp.sale_price", "fp.created_at", "fp.updated_at")
->JOIN(foduu_details_product as fdp ,fp.id ,=, fdp.product_id) 
->JOIN(foduu_category_product as fcp,fp.id, =,fcp.product_id)
->JOIN(foduu_filemanager as  ff,fp.filemanager_id ,=, ff.id)
->JOIN(foduu_categories as fc, fcp.category_id,=, fc.id) ->where(fc.slug, $slug)->where(fp.approved, 1)
->where(fp.status, 1)
->orderBy(sale_price, DESC)->get();
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

You should add single- or double-quotes around all of your string literals.
For example:

```
->JOIN('foduu_details_product as fdp', 'fp.id','=', 'fdp.product_id')
```

If it's still not working you should post the error message here.